# How to download TFS code into local workspace using command line

Tags: command-line, tfs

Can anyone help me with the steps to download TFS code to local workspace using command line.

I tried below codes so far but got into multiple issues

```
 var rv = ProcessHelper.Run(
            LocalWorkspace,
            @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
```

Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\tf.exe",
                $"get \"https://xxxx/tfs/xyz/Project/_versionControl?path=%24%2FProject\" \"{LocalWorkspace}\"");

For the above code, it says Path is not supported or specified

Comment: What steps have you taken to solve the problem on your own? Did you look at documentation? Google?

Comment: I added one of the codes I tried and the error details in the main body. I also tried another solution from "https://gist.github.com/software-mariodiana/e2ab5eb9a9ed4ed441f2" but I am getting error resolving TfsTeamProjectCollection. Error says "Unable to load type..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution to download the TFS directory into local workspace. Hope this code will get future generations.

1. create a local workspace in some temp folder

   ```
    LocalWorkspace = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), $"{Guid.NewGuid():n}");

       if (!Directory.Exists(LocalWorkspace))
       {
           Directory.CreateDirectory(LocalWorkspace);
       }

   ProcessHelper.Run(
         LocalWorkspace,
         @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
    Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team 
    Explorer\tf.exe",
         $"workspace /new /noprompt /collection:<your project url> /location:local 
   <workspace name>")
   ```
2. Get the latest version of TFS into that local workspace

   ```
    ProcessHelper.Run(
           LocalWorkspace,
           @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
    Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team 
   Explorer\tf.exe",
           $"get <TeamProject> /recursive"));
   ```

ProcessHelper.Run():

```
   public sealed class ProcessHelper
    {
    private static string outputData;

    public static string Run(string workingDirectory, string executable, string arguments)
    {
        outputData = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using Process proc = new Process();

            proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), workingDirectory);
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = executable;
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            proc.ErrorDataReceived += DataReceived;
            proc.OutputDataReceived += DataReceived;
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine();

            proc.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return $"{executable} | {workingDirectory} | {arguments}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
        }

        return $"{executable} | {workingDirectory} | {arguments}{Environment.NewLine}{Environment.NewLine}{outputData}";
    }

    static void DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string data = e.Data;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data);
            outputData += data;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for that sample, you need to add necessary assembly references to your project, then use them like this:

```
   using System.IO;
   using System.Net;
   using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
   using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
   using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
   using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;
```

You may install this package to your project: [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient)

There is a sample: [DownloadDemo](https://github.com/xingyu217/DownloadDemo)

Secondly, for TF command, you could check detail commands in a build log (TFVC repository as source), for example (checkout task):

```
##[command]tf vc workspace /new /location:local /permission:Public ws_2_4 /collection:http://xxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
##[command]tf vc workfold /unmap /workspace:ws_2_4 $/ /collection:http://xxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
##[command]tf vc workfold /map /workspace:ws_2_4 $/ScrumStarain2019TFVC D:\AgentTest\vsts-agent-win-x86-2.144.2\_work\2\s /collection:http://xxx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/ /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
##[command]tf vc get /version:7 /recursive /overwrite D:\AgentTest\vsts-agent-win-x86-2.144.2\_work\2\s /loginType:OAuth /login:.,*** /noprompt
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I followed "https://gist.github.com/software-mariodiana/e2ab5eb9a9ed4ed441f2" but I ended with an  error "could not load type...." though I added above assemblies to my project from my box. So, I took a different approach to use tf.exe and create a workspace and get the latest.